# Unable to merge different log files

Tags: excel, vba

[image]Getting Run time error 1004.

Summary:- I need to copy different system generated log files all located at a permanent location to one workbook located at same or any random location.
These logs are copied from a client's server and have many thousands of lines of data in a non-formatted way.
This data is refreshed daily. It comes in the form of .log files.

Files are named as ms.log, ms.log.1, ms.log.2, and so on.[image]

My code was working fine for sometime. But since a couple of days am getting an error which states "Run time error 1004". Error says "File cannot be opened because a semicolon was expected on Line 2 position 620".

Error screen shot attached.

Line of Code where error debugger is flagged yellow:

```
Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(xStrPath & xFiles.Item(i))
```

The error comes in only one log file. If I skip that file there is no error. If I open and copy contents of that file manually, there is no error.

```
Sub CopyAllData()

Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim xToBook As Workbook
Dim xStrPath As String
Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
Dim xFile As String
Dim xFiles As New Collection
Dim i As Long
path1 = "C:\Users\BhatiaP\Desktop\Project\"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder"
If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
    xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
End If
If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
If Right(xStrPath, 1) <> "\" Then xStrPath = xStrPath & "\"
xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "*.log*")
If xFile = "" Then
    MsgBox "No files found"
    Exit Sub
End If
Do While xFile <> ""
    xFiles.Add xFile, xFile
    xFile = Dir()
Loop
Set xToBook = Workbooks.Open(path1 & "Master.xlsm")
If xFiles.Count > 0 Then
    For i = 1 To xFiles.Count
        'On Error Resume Next
        Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(xStrPath & xFiles.Item(i))
        xWb.Worksheets(1).copy After:=xToBook.Sheets(xToBook.Sheets.Count)
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveSheet.Name = xWb.Name
        On Error GoTo 0
        xWb.Close False
    Next
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please post the code you are using as a small snippet isn't useful in this case.

Comment: @alowflyingpig: Thanks for your prompt response.
Original post updated.

Answer (score 0):

The code was opening each file and copying data as it is. I tried to copy data line by line and it worked.